# how to concatenate a section of a column of data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to use a cell to define the end of a range for a formula?

Essentially, I would like to use the `JOIN()` statement to concatenate a section of a column of data.

The data starts at a cell, say A5, and runs to a cell with the word 'total' in it. I've created a cell (let's call it L12) which returns the number of rows of data that are available.

I'd like to use that cell to form part of the range details of the `JOIN()` formula thus:

```
=JOIN(" ", A5: A[the value in L12]).
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the indirect() function does exactly what I needed it to do.

See the Google function list https://support.google.com/docs/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs